# Datas from back turn into undefined even though they appear when logging them

Tags: reactjs, undefined, destructuring

I'm trying to assign values that I get from back to the object *initialvalues*. I do get those datas but they turn into undefined when assigning them to variables.

```
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";
//components
import FormikControl from "../formik/FormikControl";
import Button from "../Button";

const UpdateUserProfile = (props) => {
  const userID = 8; //(state)
  const [myDetails, setMyDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMyDetails = async () => {
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/allpeople/myDetails/${userID}`;
      const result = await axios.get(url);
      setMyDetails(result.data);
    };
    getMyDetails();

    
  }, []);
  let first_name, last_name, email, logo, phone

  if (myDetails.length) {
    const details = myDetails[0];
   first_name = details.first_name
    console.log('first_name:', first_name) //output: Manon
    
  }
  
  console.log('first_name:', first_name) // output Manon
  let initialValues = {
    first_name: first_name,
    last_name: 'dupont',
    email: 'manondupont@gmail.com',
    phone: '0600000000',
    logo: 'non renseigné',
  };


  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log("values:", values);
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/users/updateProfile/${userID}`;
    await axios.put(url, values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <Form className="signIn__form">
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="text"
              name="first_name"
              label="Prénom"
            />
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="text"
              name="last_name"
              label="Nom"
            />

             //...

            <Button
              type="submit"
              disabled={!formik.isValid}
              className={"btn btn--round"}
              value={"Modifier mon profil"}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UpdateUserProfile;
```

I do get values that I've assigned myself (in *initialValues* variable) but not the value of *first_name* even though I can log it
[image: form]
when submitting the form *first_name* is undefined. I can't understand why.
[image: console]

Comment: The first time the component is rendered, details is null. `useEffect` is an async call. All React components need to be able to render even if the data isn't there yet. You need to wrap all the stuff after the `useEffect` in an `if(myDetails.length > 0)` or similar strategy to handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array starts out empty:

```
const [myDetails, setMyDetails] = useState([]);
```

So, when the `useEffect` runs initially, `myDetails` is an empty array, so `myDetails[0]` is `undefined`.

You see an array get logged anyway because the error is thrown *after* the `useEffect` function runs (not the callback passed to `useEffect`, but the *call* to `useEffect`).

Only try extracting elements from the array after it's been populated, eg:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
}, []);
if (myDetails.length) {
    const details = myDetails[0]
    const {
        first_name, last_name, email, logo, phone
    } = details;
    // ...
}
```

Since you're trying to use the results in a Formik component, set state to the `initialValues` inside the effect hook, then only render the Formik component once the values are populated:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then((result) => {
      setInitialValues(result.data[0])
    }).catch(handleErrors);
}, []);
// ...

return (
    <div>
      { !initialValues ? null : <Formik
        // ...
```

Comment: It's works.Thanks ! However, how I can retrieve datas outside from the if scope. I try `return details` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See edit, you need to use conditional rendering for the Formik component

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!!!!! It works. You made my day. I've been struggliing for ages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mapping through `myDetails array` in order to get the object values inside the array. E.g

```
const details = myDetails.map(detail => detail)
```

Then you can destructure the values like so,

```
{name, email,...} = details
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the OR operator you can return an empty object in case details is undefined is empty:

```
const {
  first_name, last_name, email, logo, phone
} = details || {};
```